# Decorate Entity in php/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I know how to decorate services in symfony(https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/service_container/service_decoration.html).

Is there any way to decorate entity in symfony?

I have entity Invoice and want to set absolute url to them.
Absolute url based on parameters.yml and router(injected).
I want to have for all entities with type Invoice, have absolute url.
I searched in google but can't find the way.
BTW.

I know I can use services but question is like in the title
"Is there any way to decorate entity in symfony?"

Example code(more pseudocode than working code):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service\Invoices\Decorators;

use AppBundle\Entity\Invoices;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class InvoiceAbsoluteUrlDecorator
{
    /**
     * @var string - injected from symfony parameters.yml
     */
    private $absoluteUrl;

    /** @var  Router */
    private $router;

    /** @var  Invoices */
    private $invoice;

    public function __construct($invoice, $absoluterUrl, $router)
    {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;
        $this->absoluteUrl = $absoluterUrl;
        $this->router = $router;

        $this->setInvoiceUrl($invoice);
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (!method_exists($this->invoice, $method)) {
            throw new Exception("Undefined method $method attempt in the Url class here.");
        }
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->invoice, $method), $args);
    }

    private function setInvoiceUrl($invoice)
    {
        $this->invoice->setInvoiceFileUrl(
            $this->absoluteUrl
            . $this->router->generate(
                'download_file',
                [
                    'id' => $invoice->getInvoiceFile()->getId(),
                    'byEntityId' => 0
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use an [`EntityListener`](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) to inject something *on load*.

Comment: Thank you Yoshi. This is what I was looking for. I will use postLoad event.

Comment: Could you post your resolution as an anwser please?